# How to fix error in html2pdf when we have ul tags inside another ul tags?

Tags: php, html-lists, html2pdf

I'm generating a pdf using the library HTML2PDF, and I'm facing an issue when I have a 'ul' tag inside another 'ul' tag.
Did anyone have a solution for this bug?

The error is Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable.
After debugging I found that it's related to having a ul tag inside another ul.

```
 <ul style="margin-top: 0in;" type="disc">
     <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1;">text</li> 
     <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1;">text3 </li> 
     <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1;">text2 bis</li>
     <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1;"> text1 bis</li>
     <ul style="margin-top: 0in;" type="circle">
         <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level2 lfo1;">text2</li>
         <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level2 lfo1;">text1</li>
     </ul>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this bug!
Actually, it's not a bug depending on HTML2PDF but it's related to TinyMCE (HTML Editor).
and when creating a list inside another list it will generate an HTML code with ul tag inside another ul tag.
The solution is to add lists to the plugins when init tinyMCE.

```
tinyMCE.init({
...
plugins : "lists",
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not bug, but incorrect HTML you're putting in. You can have UL inside, but it has to be as following:

```
 <ul style="margin-top: 0in;" type="disc">
   <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1;">text</li> 
   <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1;">text3 </li> 
   <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1;">text2 bis</li>
   <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1;"> text1 bis</li>
   <li>
     <ul style="margin-top: 0in;" type="circle">
       <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level2 lfo1;">text2</li>
       <li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-list: l0 level2 lfo1;">text1</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Have a look https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Comment: it's a code generated automatically from TinyMCE: The Most Advanced WYSIWYG HTML Editor

Comment: It may be advanced, but I would not call it most advanced, most of the time it is generating inproper HTML, as good example is inline styles used. You can click on code and fix it.

Comment: I'm not calling it advanced. I have just copy and past the name from there website.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3076 you're welcome, here's is bug reported